# Can devices connected on separate bands on a dual band router share files?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dual-band

I'm just about to get a Linksys WRT610N Dualband router, and I'm wondering if two devices can see each other 'across bands'?

This particular router requires separate SSIDs for each band - 2.4k and 5k. I will probably have a PC sitting on the 2.4 band, and a laptop on the 5. Will they be able to 'see' each other and share files etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

802.11a cannot interoperate with 802.11g unless dual-mode network adapters or APs are used, thats why your router requires separate SSIDs for each band. you should set your router to not interconnect their clients AND/OR use different subnet for each one, and it should be okay.